about the mathematics of sorting networks from computer science
Well, I had some searching about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network but it looks to me that all my findings focus on programming issues (in which I'm interested, too) but lack a clear mathematical background.
What I have gathered is, this is for effective sorting of n (number fixed in advance) different items (think of it as integers) with as little as possible "swaps", in a prearranged way the "swaps" are executed or not. A "swap" in programming is what mathematicians call a transposition.
Question is: is there a "framework", a strictly mathematical formulation of this problem?

So, what's your question?

My question is if there is a mathematical framework to describe that problem, and hopefully some links to more information on that subject.

There's a very interesting (pure math) paper on random sorting networks here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609538
